# Active Directory Adding User Properties

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryentry

I am trying to add a property/attribute to a user entry in Active Directory.  I don't have any trouble updating property values using the following code.

```
string LDAPString = "LDAP://DC=oc,DC=edu";
DirectoryEntry ou = new DirectoryEntry(LDAPString, "fakeUsername", "password");

DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(ou);
searcher.Filter = "sAMAccountName=" + username;
SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

DirectoryEntry user = new DirectoryEntry(result.Path, "fakeUsername", "password");

user.Properties[propertyName].Value = propertyValue;

user.CommitChanges();

user.Dispose();
```

However when I try to add a new item and call `CommitChanges()` it throws an error:

> The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.

The ExtendedErrorMessage says the following:

> 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090B8A, comment: Error in attribute
>   conversion operation, data 0, v1db1

```
string propertyName = "test";
string propertyValue = "testValue";
user.Properties[propertyName].Add(propertyValue);
user.CommitChanges();
```

I have a feeling I am missing something simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Has that new property been defined in Active Directory? Have you extended the AD schema?? You cannot just set arbitrary new properties in AD ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand that typically a property/attribute does not appear unless it is populated with a value.  As marc_s alluded to the property is already there in the schema you just have to populate it with a value.

Comment: "Not populated with a value?" That's not it.

The real secret is that you need a schema change.